# XSLT 1.0: apply-templates and template mode

Tags: xslt, mode, apply-templates

I have the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Order>
<Item>
    <RECORD_ID>RECORD_ID</RECORD_ID>
    <ENTITY_CODE>ENTITY_CODE</ENTITY_CODE>
    <USER_CODE>USER_CODE</USER_CODE>
    <RECORD_DATE>RECORD_DATE</RECORD_DATE>
    <ITEM_CODE>ITEM_CODE</ITEM_CODE>
    <LINE_QUANTITY>LINE_QUANTITY</LINE_QUANTITY>
    <LINE_FREE_STOCK>LINE_FREE STOCK</LINE_FREE_STOCK>
    <LINE_PRICE>LINE_PRICE</LINE_PRICE>
    <LINE_DISCOUNT_PERCENT>LINE_DISCOUNT PERCENT</LINE_DISCOUNT_PERCENT>
</Item>
<Item>
    <RECORD_ID>9046</RECORD_ID>
    <ENTITY_CODE>12010601</ENTITY_CODE>
    <USER_CODE>122</USER_CODE>
    <RECORD_DATE>2011-08-24</RECORD_DATE>
    <ITEM_CODE>804-008165</ITEM_CODE>
    <LINE_QUANTITY>2</LINE_QUANTITY>
    <LINE_FREE_STOCK>1</LINE_FREE_STOCK>
</Item>
<Item>
    <RECORD_ID>9046</RECORD_ID>
    <ENTITY_CODE>12010601</ENTITY_CODE>
    <USER_CODE>122</USER_CODE>
    <RECORD_DATE>2011-08-24</RECORD_DATE>
    <ITEM_CODE>804-008161</ITEM_CODE>
    <LINE_QUANTITY>1</LINE_QUANTITY>
    <LINE_FREE_STOCK>1</LINE_FREE_STOCK>
</Item>
<Item>
    <RECORD_ID>9046</RECORD_ID>
    <ENTITY_CODE>12010601</ENTITY_CODE>
    <USER_CODE>122</USER_CODE>
    <RECORD_DATE>2011-08-24</RECORD_DATE>
    <ITEM_CODE>804-008225</ITEM_CODE>
    <LINE_QUANTITY>5</LINE_QUANTITY>
</Item>
</Order>
```

Sometimes within the `item` tag I have the element `<LINE_FREE_STOCK>`. If that occurs I have to create an additional position in the output XML.

Now I came up with this style sheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <ORDERS05>
        <IDOC BEGIN="1">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Order"/>
        </IDOC>
    </ORDERS05>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Order">
    <Header>
        <xsl:value-of select="'some header data'"/>
    </Header>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Item[position() >1]"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Item[position() >1 and child::LINE_FREE_STOCK]" mode="freestock"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Item">
        <position>
            <item>
                <number><xsl:value-of select="ITEM_CODE"/></number>
                <quantity><xsl:value-of select="LINE_QUANTITY"/></quantity>
            </item>
        </position>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Item[position() >1 and child::LINE_FREE_STOCK]" mode="freestock">
        <position>
            <item>
                <number><xsl:value-of select="ITEM_CODE"/></number>
                <freestock_quant><xsl:value-of select="LINE_FREE_STOCK"/></freestock_quant>
            </item>
        </position>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It creates this (simplified) wanted output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ORDERS05>
<IDOC BEGIN="1">
    <Header>some header data</Header>
    <position>
        <item>
            <number>804-008165</number>
            <quantity>2</quantity>
        </item>
    </position>
    <position>
        <item>
            <number>804-008161</number>
            <quantity>1</quantity>
        </item>
    </position>
    <position>
        <item>
            <number>804-008225</number>
            <quantity>5</quantity>
        </item>
    </position>
    <position>
        <item>
            <number>804-008165</number>
            <freestock_quant>1</freestock_quant>
        </item>
    </position>
    <position>
        <item>
            <number>804-008161</number>
            <freestock_quant>1</freestock_quant>
        </item>
    </position>
</IDOC>
</ORDERS05>
```

804-008165 and 804-008161 show up twice - once as a standard item and once as the free stock item with the respective quantities.

But did I forget anything here? Is there some sort of pitfall I don't see?
Is that XSLT robust enough?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**As others have noted, the problem is in this code**:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="Item"/> 
<xsl:apply-templates select="Item[child::LINE_FREE_STOCK]" mode="freestock"/>
```

If there is a child `Item` that has a child `LINE_FREE_STOCK`, templates would be applied on this `Item` element twice -- here is how you get the repetitions in the output.

**The transformation can be significantly shortened and it doesn't need modes or explicit conditional instructions at all**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
    <ORDERS05>
        <IDOC BEGIN="1">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Order"/>
        </IDOC>
    </ORDERS05>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Order">
    <Header>
        <xsl:value-of select="'some header data'"/>
    </Header>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Item[position() >1]"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Item">
  <position>
    <item>
      <number>
        <xsl:value-of select="ITEM_CODE"/>
      </number>

      <xsl:apply-templates select=
        "self::node()[not(LINE_FREE_STOCK)]/LINE_QUANTITY
       |
         LINE_FREE_STOCK"/>
     </item>
  </position>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="LINE_QUANTITY">
   <quantity>
     <xsl:value-of select="."/>
   </quantity>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="LINE_FREE_STOCK">
   <freestock_quant>
     <xsl:value-of select="."/>
   </freestock_quant>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<Order>
    <Item>
        <RECORD_ID>RECORD_ID</RECORD_ID>
        <ENTITY_CODE>ENTITY_CODE</ENTITY_CODE>
        <USER_CODE>USER_CODE</USER_CODE>
        <RECORD_DATE>RECORD_DATE</RECORD_DATE>
        <ITEM_CODE>ITEM_CODE</ITEM_CODE>
        <LINE_QUANTITY>LINE_QUANTITY</LINE_QUANTITY>
        <LINE_FREE_STOCK>LINE_FREE STOCK</LINE_FREE_STOCK>
        <LINE_PRICE>LINE_PRICE</LINE_PRICE>
        <LINE_DISCOUNT_PERCENT>LINE_DISCOUNT PERCENT</LINE_DISCOUNT_PERCENT>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <RECORD_ID>9046</RECORD_ID>
        <ENTITY_CODE>12010601</ENTITY_CODE>
        <USER_CODE>122</USER_CODE>
        <RECORD_DATE>2011-08-24</RECORD_DATE>
        <ITEM_CODE>804-008165</ITEM_CODE>
        <LINE_QUANTITY>2</LINE_QUANTITY>
        <LINE_FREE_STOCK>1</LINE_FREE_STOCK>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <RECORD_ID>9046</RECORD_ID>
        <ENTITY_CODE>12010601</ENTITY_CODE>
        <USER_CODE>122</USER_CODE>
        <RECORD_DATE>2011-08-24</RECORD_DATE>
        <ITEM_CODE>804-008161</ITEM_CODE>
        <LINE_QUANTITY>1</LINE_QUANTITY>
        <LINE_FREE_STOCK>1</LINE_FREE_STOCK>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <RECORD_ID>9046</RECORD_ID>
        <ENTITY_CODE>12010601</ENTITY_CODE>
        <USER_CODE>122</USER_CODE>
        <RECORD_DATE>2011-08-24</RECORD_DATE>
        <ITEM_CODE>804-008225</ITEM_CODE>
        <LINE_QUANTITY>5</LINE_QUANTITY>
    </Item>
</Order>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<ORDERS05>
   <IDOC BEGIN="1">
      <Header>some header data</Header>
      <position>
         <item>
            <number>804-008165</number>
            <freestock_quant>1</freestock_quant>
         </item>
      </position>
      <position>
         <item>
            <number>804-008161</number>
            <freestock_quant>1</freestock_quant>
         </item>
      </position>
      <position>
         <item>
            <number>804-008225</number>
            <quantity>5</quantity>
         </item>
      </position>
   </IDOC>
</ORDERS05>
```

Comment: Hello Dimitre, Thank you for your answer. Sorry, I did not formulate my question well enough. The output I got was what I wanted. 1 position per LINE_QUANTITY and one per LINE_FREE_STOCK. I wanted some sort of confirmation I was doing it right. I did change my code though to "Item[position() >1]" in order to get rid of the xsl:if. Your posts are always elaborated, always interesting to read them! Thank you and best regards, Peter

Answer (score 1):

This is because you have two match templates for Item:

```
<xsl:template match="Item">
  <xsl:if test="position() &gt; 1">
    <position>
      <item>
        <number><xsl:value-of select="ITEM_CODE"/></number>
        <quantity><xsl:value-of select="LINE_QUANTITY"/></quantity>
      </item>
    </position>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Item[child::LINE_FREE_STOCK]" mode="freestock">
  <xsl:if test="position() &gt; 1">            
    <position>
      <item>
        <number><xsl:value-of select="ITEM_CODE"/></number>
        <freestock_quant><xsl:value-of select="LINE_FREE_STOCK"/></freestock_quant>
      </item>
    </position>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

First the default Item template matches and then the Item's with LINE_FREE_STOCK also matches the Item with child LINE_FREE_STOCK template, hence the duplicate for Item's with LINE_FREE_STOCK.

Instead why not just use one template, like this:

```
<xsl:template match="Item">
  <xsl:if test="position() &gt; 1">
    <position>
      <item>
        <number><xsl:value-of select="ITEM_CODE"/></number>
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="child::LINE_FREE_STOCK">
            <freestock_quant><xsl:value-of select="LINE_FREE_STOCK"/></freestock_quant>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <quantity><xsl:value-of select="LINE_QUANTITY"/></quantity>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </item>
    </position>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Using the single template your Order template is also simplified:

```
<xsl:template match="Order">
  <Header>
    <xsl:value-of select="'some header data'"/>
  </Header>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="Item"/>
</xsl:template>
```

This way you do not need to use Modes either.

Comment: Hello Paul, Thank you for your response. Sorry, I did not formulate my question well enough. I only wanted my code to be revised. The output I got is what I wanted. 1 recordset per "LINE_QUANTITY" and one per "LINE_FREE_STOCK". 1+ for your efforts - Thank you, Peter

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what is the wanted output. Perhaps you want:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="Item[not(LINE_FREE_STOCK)"/>
<xsl:apply-templates select="Item[LINE_FREE_STOCK]" mode="freestock"/>
```

in place of your

```
  <xsl:apply-templates select="Item"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="Item[child::LINE_FREE_STOCK]" mode="freestock"/>
```

Comment: Hello empo, yes- you are right. I did not formulate my question well enough. Sorry about that. The output I got was what I wanted. I only wanted some sort of confirmation it was the right way to do it. 1+ for your efforts and best regards, Peter

Answer (score 1):

You would need an addition filtering

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <ORDERS05>
        <IDOC BEGIN="1">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Order"/>
        </IDOC>
    </ORDERS05>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Order">
    <Header>
        <xsl:value-of select="'some header data'"/>
    </Header>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Item[not(child::LINE_FREE_STOCK)]"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Item[child::LINE_FREE_STOCK]" mode="freestock"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Item">
    <xsl:if test="position() &gt; 1">
        <position>
            <item>
                <number><xsl:value-of select="ITEM_CODE"/></number>
                <quantity><xsl:value-of select="LINE_QUANTITY"/></quantity>
            </item>
        </position>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Item[child::LINE_FREE_STOCK]" mode="freestock">
    <xsl:if test="position() &gt; 1">            
        <position>
            <item>
                <number><xsl:value-of select="ITEM_CODE"/></number>
                <freestock_quant><xsl:value-of select="LINE_FREE_STOCK"/></freestock_quant>
            </item>
        </position>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hello user905927, Thank you for your response. Sorry, I did not formulate my question well enough. I only wanted my code to be revised. The output I got is what I wanted. 1 recordset per "LINE_QUANTITY" and one per "LINE_FREE_STOCK". 1+ for your efforts - Thank you, Peter